# Entries field within structure

Tags: categories, structure

Not sure whether it's a bug or the correct behavior. How do I see the parent category just like the categories do?

[image]

[image]

Entries field related to the category group (another project)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the correct behaviour - at the time of writing, the core difference between categories and structure sections is that the relationship data for categories includes all the ancestor items, whereas a relationship to a child entry in a structure section only relates to that single item. In your particular use case of States > Cities I would probably use a category group instead of a structure section.

If that's not feasible, you could add an inline template as a UI Element in the field layout, in which you can use Twig to show a link to the parent.

[image: screenshot of UI Elements interface to select a template in a field layout]

Comment: I see but is there a way to make it look the native way just like the categories do? https://i.imgur.com/YKPQF8j.png  -  {{ element.location.one().parent.title }}